# if statement with multiple columns and conditions

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

With the following sample data I'm trying to create a new variable "category" based on the values of three columns variables (type, addict, and sex).

But I would like to combine `type` and `addict` into one group and `sex` in another group.
So I use `any` to get logically to a set of logical vectors, is at least one of the values true or both of them true.

```
df <- data.frame(type = c(NA, "bad",NA), addict=c('visky','wine',NA),
                 sex=c(NA,'male',NA))


> df
  type addict  sex
1 <NA>  visky <NA>
2  bad   wine male
3 <NA>   <NA> <NA>

library(dplyr)


df%>%
  mutate(category=ifelse(any(is.na(type)&addict=="visky")&any(is.na(sex)),"categ1",
         ifelse(any(type=="bad"|addict=="wine")&any(!is.na(sex)),"categ2",
         ifelse(any(is.na(type)&is.na(addict))&any(is.na(sex)),"categ3",NA))))

            
       type addict  sex category
1 <NA>  visky <NA>   categ1
2  bad   wine male   categ1
3 <NA>   <NA> <NA>   categ1
```

as it can be seen my `ifelse` loop is not working correctly. I cannot figured out why?

the expected output

```
       type addict  sex category
1 <NA>  visky <NA>   categ1
2  bad   wine male   categ2
3 <NA>   <NA> <NA>   categ3
```

Thx in advance

## Update for user defined function `category`

One more thing If I wanted to write user defined function without using case_when to do the same operation I would probably use

```
categ <- function(type,addict,sex){ 

if (any(is.na(type)&addict=="visky"&is.na(sex))){ 
"categ1" 
} 
else{ 
NA 
} 

}
```

but this is also gives

```
df%>%
mutate(category=categ(type,addict,sex))

  type addict  sex category
1 <NA>  visky <NA>   categ1
2  bad   wine male   categ1
3 <NA>   <NA> <NA>   categ1
```

Comment: With `==` if there are `NA` elements, it returns as NA.  So, probably you need an `&` `is.na` along with it

Comment: Also, when you wrap with `any` in the first condition, the output is a single TRUE/FALSE, which gets recycled across

Comment: @akrun I thought is.na should return `TRUE`. what do you mean using `&` `is.na` along with it?

Comment: Can you show the expected output?

Comment: @akrun so any(TRUE&TRUE)&any(TRUE) should all return TRUE I think ?

Comment: What happens is that it is doing the `any` on the entire column to get a single TRUE/FALSE, which is not what you want\

Comment: @akrun please check the OP. I updated it !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the OP's input dataset, all the columns were `factor` and along with that `NA`s were string `"NA"`.  Also, the OP's code is checking the entire column with `any` which returns a single `TRUE/FALSE` and gets recycled which is not the intended output.  If we change those to `character` class and to `NA`s (using `case_when`)

```
df %>% 
  mutate(category = case_when(
            is.na(type) & addict %in% "visky" & is.na(sex) ~ "categ1",
            type %in% c("bad", "wine") & !is.na(sex) ~ "categ2", 
            is.na(type) & is.na(addict) & is.na(sex) ~ "categ3", 
            TRUE ~ NA_character_))
#   type addict  sex category
#1 <NA>  visky <NA>   categ1
#2  bad   wine male   categ2
#3 <NA>   <NA> <NA>   categ3
```

NOTE: Here, we are used `%in%` instead of `==` as `==` returns NA for NA elements while `%in%` returns FALSE.  But, we could still use `==` with a combination of `is.na`

---

Based on the OP's comments, we could create a custom function (different function)

```
categFn <- function(typeCol, addictCol, sexCol) {

           if(any(is.na(typeCol) & addictCol== "visky") & any(is.na(sexCol))) {
               "categ1"
              } else NA
            }

df %>% 
     mutate(categ = categFn(type, addict, sex))
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(type = c(NA, "bad",NA), addict=c('visky','wine',NA),
                  sex=c(NA,'male',NA), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: thx I fixed the OP. Soory about the misconfusion. One more thing If I wanted to write user defined function without using `case_when` to do the same operation I usually use 
`categ <- function(type,addict,sex){
  
  if (any(is.na(type)&addict=="visky"&is.na(sex))){
    "categ1"
  }
  else{
    
    NA
  }
}`

Comment: @ok I added this part to under the OP. for user defined category function!

Comment: @Alexander Do you want to use `ifelse` only? or is it a different function

Comment: I mean `ifelse` more natural to me and loving it more;)

Comment: @Alexander I meant about the condition i.e. using `any` with `if` or the condition should be `ifelse(is.na(type) & addict == "viskey" & is.na(sex), "categ", NA)`

Comment: my problem is actually how set `any(is.na(type) & addict == "viskey") & any(is.na(sex))` either type or addict is true as a group and `sex` must be true ?

Comment: So I put them in `any` I though I was grouping them. But this is working I mean `any` if I have `group_by`. This is the first time I faced this issue in `ungrouped` data.

Comment: @Alexander Your condition returns `categ1` for all the rows.  Is that correct? `categFn <- function(data, typeCol, addictCol, sexCol) {
           typeCol <- enquo(typeCol);
     addictCol <- enquo(addictCol);
     sexCol <- enquo(sexCol);
           data %>%
       mutate(categ = 
            ifelse(any(is.na(!! typeCol) & !!(addictCol) == "visky") & any(is.na(!! sexCol)), "categ1", NA))
   }`

Comment: i.e. `with(df, any(is.na(type) & addict == "visky") & any(is.na(sex)))#
[1] TRUE`  So, it gives all elements as `categ1`

Comment: so 'with' can be used in user defined function? ı would appreciate if you could add this user defined function to the solution . Because sometimes my conditions are too long and I need to have some function in another place not inside of the dplyr chain. sorry for asking to much;)